# Convert formally logical description into control scheme

Tags: logic, logical-operators

I want to extend a Bang-Bang control (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang%E2%80%93bang_control) with a certain time, that the controller has to be on/off.

I would like to translate the following assignments into a logical control scheme:

(BangBang is True AND Controller was long enough off) -> Switch_On

(BangBang is False AND Controller was long enough on) -> Switch_Off

I know how to do it just for the first one:

[image]

The output of "calculate how long BangBang is false" is the time for how long the output is already false; which is then compared in the block "greater" with a certain value. As soon as it is great, the output of the model "greater" become true.

In the end i would like a logical control scheme with a single output tha tis true/false.

[image]

Would be great if somebody could help me.